# Laravel Homestead/Vagrant box error : The specified checksum type is not supported by Vagrant: sha512

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I am trying to install laravel homestead and can't get past adding the homestead box.

The instruction is: `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`

After completing the download process following error appears.

```
C:\Users\HARSHA - PC PRO>vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v9.0.1) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/9.0.1/providers/virtualbox.box
==> box: Box download is resuming from prior download progress
    box: Download redirected to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 188k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
    box: Calculating and comparing box checksum...
The specified checksum type is not supported by Vagrant: sha512.
Vagrant supports the following checksum types:

md5, sha1, sha256
```

I'm on Windows 10 64 bit PC and have tried these instructions with the virtualbox(Version 6.0.0 r127566 (Qt5.6.2)) and vagrant_2.2.2_x86_64 version.

I'm trying to install Laravel homestead and am not aware of resolving this since I am new to the Laravel vagrant. I searched the web for the particular problem and I could not find any solution pertaining to the above, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned in Vagrant's [CHANGELOG.md file](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#226-october-14-2019), new checksum types are now supported. Simply [updating Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) to its latest version (2.2.6) should do the trick.

You can then do `vagrant box update` to upgrade the Homestead box.

Comment: Unfortunately there is another issue with checksum preventing laravel homestead from working with 2.2.6. I had the problem with 2.2.6 so I downloaded the 2.2.5 version and then got this error.

Comment: @KodosJohnson so you're having this issue on both 2.2.5 and 2.2.6 ?

Comment: Not the same issue. In 2.2.6 I get this problem: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11226. But it looks like this has been fixed but hasn't been released yet. But I got around my problem by using 2.2.5 and using an older homestead box (v8.2.1)

Comment: i did this and i still get the same problem

Comment: @Ari can you confirm you're using 2.2.6 (using `vagrant -v`) ?

Comment: Fedora 30, with vagrant 2.2.5 (latest release through official channel) also has the sha512 problem. I also had to add the line "version: 8.2.1" to the ~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml file (once git clone etc had been run). Without this last bit, it would keep trying to upgrade to latest during the vagrant up command.

Comment: Oh and just realized it might only apply to the virtualbox image file. Previously I had success with unintentional hyperv box add ... box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v9.1.1) for 'hyperv'! On the same Fedora 30 machine. @Ari does this apply to you?

Comment: On OSX I had vagrant installed with brew, so I could simply `brew cask install vagrant` or `brew cask upgrade vagrant` to upgrade to 2.2.6. Then I ran `vagrant box update` again and 512 was supported.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I saw in the logs that the version trying to get installed was **v9.2.2-alpha1**

> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v9.2.2-alpha1) for provider:
>   virtualbox

What worked for me is defining the version by using the following parameter

```
--box-version=9.1.1
```

i.e.

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead --checksum-type=sha256 --box-version=9.1.1
```

Also, try to download and install the latest version of vagrant.

Answer (score 8):

You are using the unsupported checksum type.try installing with **`--checksum-type`** parameter. Given below,

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead --checksum-type sha256
```

Here is the [Docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#checksum-type-type) to refer to while using command-line.

Comment: This didn't work for me; I still got the same error. I presume the source was only providing sha512 checksums and no others.

Comment: You can try running it in debug mode. Pass `--debug` to get more info about the issue.

Comment: Maybe so. I just upgraded vagrant instead and that resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try 2.2.7 version.

vagrant -v

Vagrant 2.2.7

==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v9.3.0) for 'virtualbox'!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it took multiple attempts.

**Problems**

- Couldn't update the vagrant box.
- Once I downloaded it wouldn't switch to the new box.
- Once I switched Laravel threw a Facade error.

**Solution**
(with many thank you's to the answers in this thread):

1. Navigate to the Homestead/Vagrant folder.
2. Then run "vagrant -v" to check your Vagrant version (ex. "Vagrant 2.1.5").
3. In a web browser go to https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html .
4. Download the latest Vagrant version.
5. On your computer, run and install the new version.
6. Go to: https://www.virtualbox.org/
7. Download the lastest Virtual Machine.
8. On your computer, run and install the new version.
9. Back in the terminal, check the vagrant version again "vagrant -v" (ex. "Vagrant 2.2.10").
10. Make sure your Vagrant is stopped by running "vagrant halt".
11. Purge and reinstall your vagrant plugins to be safe with "vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall" (and confirm "Y").
12. Now run "vagrant box update" to update your box.
13. Now load your box with "vagrant up".
14. With your box loaded run "vagrant destroy".
15. Now run "vagrant up" again to rebuild your box from scratch.

This worked for me. Let me know if this works for you.